# How to update api request from postman (form-data) with Laravel update controller?

Tags: laravel, api, request, postman, updates

Postman response

[image]

my postman request

[image]

- Update method controller

I am trying to update the request but return null data from the postman response

```
          $person_ask_per = PersonAskPermission::find($person_ask_per_id);
  
          $person_ask_per->day = $request->day;
          $person_ask_per->person_id = $request->person_id;
          .....

          $person_ask_per->save();
  
          return  $person_ask_per
```

Comment: What are you sending from Postam?

Comment: please click the link above I recently add picture.

Comment: from where you are getting `$person_ask_per_id`

Comment: ````public function update(Request $request, $person_ask_per_id)
    {
        $person_ask_per = PersonAskPermission::with('getTypes', 'getReasons', 'getPerson')->find($person_ask_per_id);

        $person_ask_per->start = $request->start;
        $person_ask_per->end = $request->end;
        $person_ask_per->day = $request->day;
        $person_ask_per->person_id = $request->person_id;
        $person_ask_per->file = $request->file; ````

Comment: ``$person_ask_per->getTypes()->attach($request->permission_type_id);
        $person_ask_per->getReasons()->attach($request->permission_reason_id);
        $person_ask_per->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Person Ask Permission updated successfully!',
            'data' => $person_ask_per
        ]);
    }``

Comment: write `$person_ask_per->update();` instead of `$person_ask_per->save();` and let me know

Comment: it still not update.

Answer (score 0):

`form-data` doesn't work for PUT requests in Laravel because `Request $request` doesn't receive the values. Use the `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead, it will work. I faced the same problem many times. Just select `x-www-form-urlencoded` in postman tab.

Comment: but in my case, I have a field file to update so, how?

Comment: it updates with null. $request->day will return null. Your can check  printing the request values. try $request->all(); You will find nothing there.

Comment: please check below code i have added full store method

Comment: For the POST request postman form-data will works fine. But for PUT request you need to  use urlenconded method to send data in postman. Assuming you used POST method for store, it works.

Comment: so when I want to replace a new file front-end can, Teacher?